# Creating links to Strings in xamarin studio

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

Am building an application where by i wand to link an image button to a string. Bellow is my code

```
ImageButton imageEnglish = FindViewById(Resource.Id.disclaimer);
```

When is debug my code, its tells me

> "resource ID does not contain a definition the disclaimer"

yet disclaimer is defined in my strings.
Kindly take me through this

Comment: Add your Imagebutton design code too.

Comment: Could you please add the xml for the layout and the strings file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

You are missing cast in your code.

```
ImageButton imageEnglish = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.disclaimer);
```

---

Check your ImageButton Id in designer too.